# PHP activating a user

Tags: php

Please understand that I do not have database access right now.

So here is what I'm doing. I have a program I'm making just for practice. I have a createaccount file that uses a form to get a username, password and email for a user. It then writes the fields to a text file and also adds an 'inactive' status to the file and then emails the user with a link for validation. When the user clicks the activation link, I need the file to check what username it is dealing with, then search the text file for the user and change the status from inactive to active.

Not really sure how to accomplish this and my code right now just keeps telling me the file was destroyed. Is there a better way to do this than destroy and recreate the file? I am new to php and I do realize that using a text file is not recommended at all, no real users will be using this script, just my own personal practice before I do it with tables.

Let me know what you think, any help is much appreciated!

```
<?php

    include 'sessions.php';

    $userid = $_GET['newUserName'];
    $Email = $_POST['newEmail'];
    $Users = file("../writeable/users.txt");
    for($i=0; $i < count($Users); $i++) { 

        $row = explode(",", $Users[$i]); 
        if ($row[$i]===$Email){

            $userstring="$row[0]".","."$row[1]".","."$row[2]".","."active\n";

            $_SESSION['active'] = TRUE;
        }

    }

    //destroy the users.txt file
    if (file_exists("../writeable/users.txt")){
        if(unlink("../writeable/users.txt")){
            echo "File destroyed, will now be recreated";
        }
    }
    else
        echo "<p>Unable to delete this file<p>";

    $Userfile = fopen("../writeable/users.txt", "w+"); //recreate the file
    $userstring = implode(",", $Users); //make the array into a string.


    fwrite($Userfile, $userstring); //write the string userstring into userfile
    if(!file_exists("../writeable/users.txt")){


        echo "<p>This file was not written<p>";

    }

?>
```

Please be gentle, again I'm new :)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I understand, and if you read my post, said I know this isn't the way to accomplish, but it is for my practice and I don't have database access right now. Looking for meaningful contributions please.

Comment: For this sort of file-based pattern, it's best to perform any updates to the file by creating a temporary copy of it, making the changes to that copy, removing the original, and then renaming the copy to the original filename. There are, of course, concurrent access issues to consider, but given that you understand that this is not an ideal solution, and that it's for practice, I won't get too hung up on that aspect.

Comment: Can you add more 'fields' to your `users.txt` file? If so, just add a unique string to the user that needs to be activated inside the file and create the activation link with it as a get param.

Comment: @still2blue Oh I see, that information should really be a stand-alone statement at the beginning of your post; especially since you do not mention it anywhere at all. I do not see how flat-file practice is going to make you a better DB programmer. If anything, it will cause you to pick up bad habits which you will have to un-learn when you go to use a DB.

Comment: @still2blue you can easily install mysql, so you do have database access.

Comment: @FirstOne I really do not want to add any fields to the file. Just want to explode the string based on the username, change the word `inactive` to `active`, then allow the user to login on the form. @MonkeyZeus I am well aware it will not make me a better DB programmer, however at this time it is what I am trying to accomplish. I know SQL well enough and also know this script is so much easier using a database, nothing more than a challenge and at this point, learning how to seek out a specific word in a string and change it based on certain parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change the way you are saving the data in the file. Serialization could help you, take a look at [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

Here is a stand alone working code that you can put in a **new file** with any name (doesn't include email, but once you get the idea, it's easy to add. Also, remeber to open the file to see the changes):

```
<?php
// change to true to create file with example (change to false to keep changes)
$firstRun = true;

if(isset($_GET['key'])){
    $file = "users.txt"; // original data in this one
    $file2 = "before.txt"; // saves what was before the edition (just to check)
    // 2 files just to see the difference

    $key = $_GET['key']; // from email link

    if($firstRun){
        /* WITHOUT unique key from associative array - this might require loop through the elements
        $data = array('username' => 'userD', 'password' => 'IamNOTencryptedX', 'active' => false, 
                      'username' => 'userC', 'password' => 'IamNOTencryptedY', 'active' => false, 
                      'username' => 'userB', 'password' => 'IamNOTencryptedZ', 'active' => false, 
                      'username' => 'userA', 'password' => 'IamNOTencrypted1', 'active' => false, 
                      'username' => 'userX', 'password' => 'IamNOTencrypted2', 'active' => false
                     );
        */
        // WITH unique key (the username in this example - could be id) - direct access
        $users = array('userD' => array('username' => 'userD', 'password' => 'IamNOTencryptedX', 'active' => false), 
                       'userC' => array('username' => 'userC', 'password' => 'IamNOTencryptedY', 'active' => false), 
                       'userB' => array('username' => 'userB', 'password' => 'IamNOTencryptedZ', 'active' => false), 
                       'userA' => array('username' => 'userA', 'password' => 'IamNOTencrypted1', 'active' => false), 
                       'userX' => array('username' => 'userX', 'password' => 'IamNOTencrypted2', 'active' => false)
                     );
        file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users)); // serialize and save to file
        $users = ""; // just to make sure, not really needed
    }

    if(file_exists($file)){ // better be safe than sorry
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($file); // read it all from file
        file_put_contents($file2, $fileContent); // create a 'backup' to file2

        $users = json_decode($fileContent, true); // true for associative array. This will recreate the array from the beginning based on the string from file

        if(isset($users[$key])){ // make sure it's in the file
            // you can check if this user is already activated too

            $users[$key]['active'] = true; // activate
            file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users)); // save back to file.
            echo "USER '".$users[$key]['username']."' ACTIVATED. <i>[redirection needed]</i>";
        }else{
            echo 'KEY \''.$key.'\' NOT FOUND.<br> <form> Easy fix -> KEY: <input type="text" name="key"><input type="submit" value="Activate">'; // just in case you get lost when testing, don't use this
        }

        echo "\n\n";

        // if you are going to use the first $data declaration, it's something like this
        /*
        foreach($users as $k => $value){
            if($value == $key){
                $users[$k]['active'] = true; // change value
                file_put_contents($file, json_encode($users));
                break;
            }
        }
        */

    }else{
        // FILE NOT CREATED BEFORE
        echo "FILE CREATED JUST NOW. IS THIS FIRST RUN?";
        file_put_contents($file, "{}");
    }
}else{
    echo 'MISSING KEY.<br> <form> Easy fix -> KEY: <input type="text" name="key"><input type="submit" value="Activate">';// just in case you get lost when testing, don't use this
}
?>
```

With this structure you can check if the username and password match just accessing the value directly.
To add new user, something like this should work (without checking if it exists):

```
$newUsername = 'still2blue'; // say this is form data
$newPassword = 'still2blue'; 
$users[$newUsername] = array('username' => $newUsername, 'password' => $newPassword, 'active' => false);
```

*I'm sorry if any of this feels too unexplained, but the power went off when I was typing the other one and I got demotivated.*

If you don't intend to change it, your code would have look something like this (superficially tested):

```
<?php
include 'sessions.php';
$fileName = "../writeable/users.txt";
$userid = $_GET['newUserName'];
$Email = $_GET['newEmail']; // changed to get
$Users = file($fileName);
$userstring = "";
$found = false;
for($i=0; $i < count($Users); $i++) { 
    $row = explode(",", $Users[$i]); // the name row here is wrong, the var $Users is equivalent to rows, this represents each 'column'
    foreach($row as $k => $c){
        if($found){ // since it's unique
            $userstring .= $row[0].",".$row[1].",".$row[2].",".$row[3].""; // the \n is already part of 'inactive'
            break;
        }elseif($c===$Email){
            $userstring .= $row[0].",".$row[1].",".$row[2].",active\n";
            $_SESSION['active'] = TRUE;
            $found = true;
            break; // no need to keep checking if it's unique
        }elseif($k == count($row)-1){ // if you checked all the 'columns' of that row and didn't find the match, add it without active
            $userstring .= $row[0].",".$row[1].",".$row[2].",".$row[3].""; // the \n is already part of 'inactive'
        }
    }
}

//destroy the users.txt file
if (file_exists($fileName)){
    if(unlink($fileName)){
        echo "File destroyed, will now be recreated";
    }
}
else
    echo "<p>Unable to delete this file<p>";

$Userfile = fopen($fileName, "w+"); //recreate the file
// removed
//$userstring = implode(",", $Users); //make the array into a string.


fwrite($Userfile, $userstring); //write the string userstring into userfile
if(!file_exists($fileName)){


    echo "<p>This file was not written<p>";

}
?>
```

Note that you might be able to achieve the save result with [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

Comment: I'm sorry my knowledge of php is pretty limited. So when my email is sent to the user, it has the activate link with the username in it. On my activate page, I start out by getting the username (it has been validated on the create account page as a unique username not in use by anyone else.) Then I need to go through an array and store a temporary copy of all the info in the users.txt file, find the user referenced and change his status to inactive, then destroy the original file and then create a new file with the new status, then direct them to the login page. Could you show example code?

Comment: I'm sorry, let me just clear something out. Is yout problem ONLY related to altering just the user part to `active` without having to read and re-writing everything else? I might have misunderstood your problem. @still2blue

Comment: Let me try to elaborate. My form takes the users input, writes a text file with each line like so: username,hashpass,email,inactive. So using a get argument from the email link the user clicked to check what username I'm dealing with, I want to go through and save all the information while looking for specific user, when he is found, change inactive to active, then destroy the original file and rewrite it with all the new info. From here they will be redirected to a login page where it will authenticate them. Appreciate your help btw

Comment: I'll edit my answer, might take some time. @still2blue

Comment: I'm heading to work but will respond later! Thank you @FirstOne !